# CSS Border-Radius Modulation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have searched online extensively, but I cannot find any discussion.

Is there a way to modulate the border radius of an object using a css animation? I am looking for something kind of like (either one of the circles, not both):

[image: Animated Border Radius]

Does anyone have a general idea if this is possible? I'm not looking for an exact replication, just a simple implementation of the border-radius effect. Thanks for any ideas.

This is about as close as I can get:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNbNPg?editors=010

```
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  25%  {border-radius: 120px 100px 120px 110px;}
  50% {border-radius: 100px 120px 110px 120px;}
  75%  {border-radius: 120px 110px 120px 100px;}
  100% {border-radius: 110px 120px 100px 120px;}
}
```

Comment: Here's my go at it without spending too much time: http://jsfiddle.net/yv9crtuk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try doing something like your code pen but add this instead. I added a border that spins like 1000 degrees lol

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    position :relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(10000deg); }
  25%  {border-radius: 50px 100px 100px 100px;}
}
```

it is getting there....
https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/avocyf33/9/ maybe someone can add to this, I wanna see this work!

or maybe some kind of take off of this? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/avocyf33/10/

**And by mistake made this pretty cool although it does not answer your question**

https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/avocyf33/11/

Comment: Haha thanks a ton @Adam Buchanan Smith. These are all really cool!!

Comment: @NickB If you ever get it finished, could you share it? I would be interested in seeing what you came up with.

Comment: Yes, will do. Looking for a cool tap (mobile) interaction that kind of ripples. With your help I'm getting closer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you would be better off pursuing that specific animation with SVG rather than CSS border-radius. SVG is more flexible because you have a variety of vector elements at your disposal and you are able to express the animation with JavaScript.

The example animation has some algebraic patterns which are really hard, if not impossible, to do with the CSS approach. Also keep in mind that you are limited to 4 "corners" per element when using border-radius.

For some inspiration , I recommend browsing Tympanus. You might see something you like in one of these CSS-only demos:
http://tympanus.net/Development/PseudoElementsAnimationsTransitions/index2.html
http://tympanus.net/Development/ButtonStylesInspiration/